What part of my code is forcing the paragraph to the right and how do I fix it?
I'm trying to get my paragraph nice and centered within its container. However it keeps pushing to the right side of the screen and the dot points won't list. I've deleted and rewritten the code, asked chatgpt and Gemini to fix it and neither can. I've put the code through a html and css validator and it all comes back fine so whatever I'm doing wrong I doing it wrong right.
I've tried the following:
added an about list class to the html which I hoped would make the list but its still in a line.
Changed margin-bottom under the about-list li which done nothing.
Change the .about-list list-style-type from none to disc which changed nothing.
Added .about-content text-align center which pushed the text further right???


.about-section {
  display: flex;
  /* Use flexbox for layout */
  align-items: center;
  /* Center items vertically */
  background-color: #5c4033;
}

.about-image {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  /* Take up 50% of the width */
  padding-right: 0px;
  /* Add some spacing between image and text */
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.about-image img {
  width: 50%;
  /* Ensure image doesn't exceed its container */
  height: auto;
  /* Maintain aspect ratio */
  margin-left: 245px;
  /*added pace to the left*/
}


/* Style the rest of the content as needed */

.about-content h2 {
  font-size: 3em;
  /* Adjust heading size as needed */
}

.about-content {
  text-align: center;
  /* Center align the text */
}

.about-paragraph {
  text-align: justify;
  /* Justify the text within the paragraph */
}

.about-list {
  list-style-type: disc;
  /* Use disc as list style */
  text-align: left;
  /* Align list items to the left */
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.about-list li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /* Add margin between list items */
}
<div class="about-section">
  <div class="about-image">
    <img
      src="Images/jonathan-borba-AgygcLrWRbk-unsplash.jpg"
      alt="About Image"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="about-content">
    <h2>About Lilac Valley</h2>
    <p class="about-paragraph">
      Escape to <em>Rustic Luxury</em> at Lilac Valley Farm Stay. Imagine waking
      up to the gentle sounds of a farmyard, surrounded by the breathtaking
      beauty of the <strong>Blue Mountains</strong>. Lilac Valley Farm Stay is
      your invitation to unwind and reconnect with nature in a beautifully
      restored luxury barn house. This hidden gem, lovingly renovated by local
      interior designer <strong>Marina Ye</strong>, offers a unique blend of
      rustic charm and modern comfort. Spread over four acres, the property
      boasts:
    </p>
    <ul class="about-list">
      <li>A stunning open-plan barn house, perfect for families or groups.</li>
      <li>An enchanting cottage garden bursting with colorful blooms.</li>
      <li>A refreshing plunge pool to cool off after a day of exploring.</li>
      <li>
        Friendly farmyard companions – sheep, chickens, ducks, and the
        ever-so-charming Rosie the goat.
      </li>
    </ul>
    <p>
      Lilac Valley Farm Stay has been a favorite amongst AirBnB guests and has
      even garnered attention online.
      <strong><em>Get ready for an unforgettable escape.</em></strong>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>



This is what it currently looks like


Can you show a mockup of how you want the site to look?  What you've described is not that clear to me.

@ScottZ link This is what it currently looks like. I'm trying to bring the paragraph into the centre of its box and made the dot points a list.

For a section which you want to be 50/50 I recommend a grid instead of a flexbox.


body {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

.about-section {
  padding: 1px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #5c4033;
}

.about-image {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.about-image img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.about-content {
  padding: 1px 2em 1em;
}

.about-content h2 {
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}

.about-paragraph {
  text-align: justify;
}

.about-list {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.about-list li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
<div class="about-section">
  <div class="about-image">
    <img
      src="http://picsum.photos/800/1200"
      alt="About Image"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="about-content">
    <h2>About Lilac Valley</h2>
    <p class="about-paragraph">
      Escape to <em>Rustic Luxury</em> at Lilac Valley Farm Stay. Imagine waking
      up to the gentle sounds of a farmyard, surrounded by the breathtaking
      beauty of the <strong>Blue Mountains</strong>. Lilac Valley Farm Stay is
      your invitation to unwind and reconnect with nature in a beautifully
      restored luxury barn house. This hidden gem, lovingly renovated by local
      interior designer <strong>Marina Ye</strong>, offers a unique blend of
      rustic charm and modern comfort. Spread over four acres, the property
      boasts:
    </p>
    <ul class="about-list">
      <li>A stunning open-plan barn house, perfect for families or groups.</li>
      <li>An enchanting cottage garden bursting with colorful blooms.</li>
      <li>A refreshing plunge pool to cool off after a day of exploring.</li>
      <li>
        Friendly farmyard companions – sheep, chickens, ducks, and the
        ever-so-charming Rosie the goat.
      </li>
    </ul>
    <p>
      Lilac Valley Farm Stay has been a favorite amongst AirBnB guests and has
      even garnered attention online.
      <strong><em>Get ready for an unforgettable escape.</em></strong>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>




thanks I was taught to use flexbox so had no clue their was another way to do it. However, I'm still having the list issue and for extra confusing if I use the run code snippet here on both my original code and your code it turns into a list yet on my site it doesn't!

Sounds like something else on your site is overriding the list styling. Use your browser inspector to figure out which styles are being applied.
